# How to add dynamic footer values to maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel export

Tags: excel, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

How to add footer to laravel Excel export? I need to show the sum of each column values in the exported Excel footer.

[image]

I need the total numbers in exported file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend You Should Write this

```
@php $totals = $your_db_data->get();
$aTotal = 0;
@endphp 
@foreach($totals as $one)
@php
$aTotal += $one->your_number_name;
@endphp
@endforeach
```

Then Inside Th or Td

```
{{$aTotal}}
```

I hope It Help You  If Not Working Rewrite To Here